# Regular expression that both includes and excludes certain strings in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to use R to parse through a number of entries. I have two requirements for the the entries I want back. I want all the entries that contain the word `apple` but don't contain the word `orange`.

For example:

1. I like apples
2. I really like apples
3. I like apples and oranges

I want to get entries 1 and 2 back.

How could I go about using R to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI added speed comparison to my late answer. Btw when I posted that answer, I was amazed at how much attention this question had already received (24 upvotes between you and the two people who had already answered!) Are you a famous actor or something? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a regular expression, you could do the following.

```
x <- c('I like apples', 'I really like apples', 
       'I like apples and oranges', 'I like oranges and apples',
       'I really like oranges and apples but oranges more')

x[grepl('^((?!.*orange).)*apple.*$', x, perl=TRUE)]
# [1] "I like apples"        "I really like apples"
```

The regular expression looks ahead to see if there's no character except a line break and no substring `orange` and if so, then the dot `.` will match any character except a line break as it is wrapped in a group, and repeated (`0` or more times). Next we look for `apple` and any character except a line break (`0` or more times).  Finally, the start and end of line anchors are in place to make sure the input is consumed.

---

**UPDATE**: You could use the following if *performance* is an issue.

```
x[grepl('^(?!.*orange).*$', x, perl=TRUE)]
```

Comment: It'd also be much more useful if you add an explanation as to how this works.

Comment: @Arun This is indeed a tricky one. The first sub-expression asks whether, starting from the position right before the first character, there is any string of characters followed by the characters "apple". If it finds one, the regular expression engine goes right back to that spot before the first character, and begins testing the negative lookahead assertion. That second subexpression is the relatively tricky one. It works by checking, at every inter-character space in the word, whether there: (a) **is** a character up ahead but (b) there **is not** the string "orange" right up ahead.

Comment: Equivalently, do `grep('^(?=.*apple)((?!orange).)*$', x, perl=T, value=T)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks. I was able to (sort-of) understand what it was doing :), but wouldn't have been able to dissect it as you did.

Comment: @Arun -- I had a similar reaction. It actually looked provably wrong to me at first, but after several minutes of trying, I couldn't break it. I'm glad I cracked it b/c it's the kind of puzzle that can get stuck in my head like a tenacious earworm!

Answer (score 23):

Could do

```
temp <- c("I like apples", "I really like apples", "I like apples and oranges")
temp[grepl("apple", temp) & !grepl("orange", temp)]

## [1] "I like apples"      "I really like apples"
```

Comment: I am not sure about performance etc, but I think this reads much much clearer then anything else! Specially if you have to exclude several words!

Comment: @drmariod adding `fixed = TRUE` to both `grepl` calls will make this a very competitive solution.

Comment: Thanks, it is always a pleasure reading your answers! At the moment I just use it over a few hundred elements but will keep this in mind!

Comment: FWIW this solution worked for me after asking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553709/how-can-i-exclude-a-string-pattern-after-looking-for-a-string-pattern-in-the-sam, but the other solutions didn't work

Answer (score 12):

This regex is a bit smaller and much faster than the other regex versions (see comparison below). I don't have the tools to compare to David's double `grepl` so if someone can compare the single `grep` below vs the double `grepl` we'll be able to know. The comparison must be done both for a success case and a failure case.

```
^(?!.*orange).*apple.*$
```

1. The negative lookahead ensures we don't have `orange`
2. We just match the string, so long as it contains `apple`. No need for a lookahead there.

**Code Sample**

```
grep("^(?!.*orange).*apple.*$", subject, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);
```

**Speed Comparison**

@hwnd has now removed that double lookahead version, but according to RegexBuddy the speed difference remains:

1. Against `I like apples and oranges`, the engine takes 22 steps to fail, vs. 143 for the double lookahead version `^(?=.*apple)((?!orange).)*$` and 22 steps for `^((?!.*orange).)*apple.*$` (equal there but wait for point 2).
2. Against `I really like apples`, the engine takes 64 steps to succeed, vs. 104 for the double lookahead version `^(?=.*apple)((?!orange).)*$` and 538 steps for `^((?!.*orange).)*apple.*$`.

These numbers were provided by the RegexBuddy debugger.

Comment: Yes, this is IMHO much better, mostly because it's quite a bit easier to grock.

Comment: @hwnd Ha, you felt like boggling people, that's great!... Sometimes, I do the same, but by mistake (leaving a lookahead where a straight match would have worked). :)

Comment: My next question to Josh would've been on speed. Thanks for answering that.

Comment: @hwnd, why would David's double grepl be faster than my single grep? I don't have the tools to test, but that's not intuitive for me.

Comment: @tehAlgorithmist Did one of the asnwers solve it for you, or are you still wrestling with it? Please let us know. :)